# Checking if this set is a vector sp.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

**Question:** Define a set $V=\{(x,y):x,y\in\Bbb R\}$. For any two elements $u=(u_1,u_2),v=(v_1,v_2)$ in $V$ and $t\in\Bbb R$, addition and scalar multiplication as,

$$u+v=(u_1+v_1,u_1v_1)\quad\textrm{and}\quad tv=(tv_1,v_2)$$

Is $V$ a vector space over $\Bbb R$ ?

**Attempt:**

I found out with a bit of examination that $V$ isn't a vector space. So, I used the following method to show that $V$ isn't a vector space.

We proceed by using contradiction. Assume that $V$ is a vector space. Let $\theta=(\alpha,\beta)$ denote the zero vector of supposed vector space $V$. Then, we have,$~\forall~(u_1,u_2)\in V$,

$$(u_1,u_2)+(\alpha,\beta)=(u_1,u_2)\implies (u_1+\alpha,u_2\beta)=(u_1,u_2)\implies \theta=(\alpha,\beta)=(0,1)$$

Now, consider $(3,0)$ which $\in V$. Since $V$ is supposed vector space, there should exist an additive inverse of $(3,0)$ in $V$, i.e., a vector $(l_1,l_2)\in V$ such that,

$$(3,0)+(l_1,l_2)=\theta=(0,1)\implies 0\cdot l_2=1\implies 0=1$$

which is absurd. Hence, our original assumption is wrong and we conclude that $V$ isn't a vector space.

---

Is my solution correct? Note that I'm a beginner at linear algebra (my classes just started 2-3 weeks ago), so please be kind to me. ^_^

Comment: Your solution looks good to me.